# How is authentication LoginPath being overridden?

Tags: authentication, identity-server

Sitecore 8.2r170728, MVC 5, and AspNet Identity

We want to require direct links to pages of our site that require a logged in user to redirect to our login page and then return to the originally requested page.

This is working in my local dev environment but not when I deploy to higher environments like UA. As far as I can tell, the two environments are configured the same.

In my local environment, I see the desired result:

[image]

In my UA environment, I see the undesired result:

[image]

The request should be redirected to `/account-login?ReturnUrl=...` instead of `/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=...`

My ConfigureAuth code:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/account-login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

    // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
    // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
    // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
}
```

I don't see anything that stands out in my sites config. I'm not sure what else could be causing the differences. Where would `/login.aspx` be coming from in my UA?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96622/discussion-on-question-by-fgantt-how-is-authentication-loginpath-being-overridde).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused by the `Forms` authentication mode defined in `web.config`.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="/Login.aspx" timeout="1440" />
</authentication>
```

Find `<authentication` node in your `web.config` and compare it with your local environment.

Most probably it's set to `None` in your local like:

```
<authentication mode="None">
```

Comment: Should be set to none.

Comment: Thanks @josedbaez . Yeah, it should be set to none. Answer updated.